# PHP Question - Safe mode error when setting timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I'm trying to install a [PHP application](http://www.timesheetng.org/) on my server.  But I'm getting this error:

> Warning: putenv() [function.putenv]:
>   Safe Mode warning: Cannot set
>   environment variable 'PHP_TZ' - it's
>   not in the allowed list in
>   .../public/timezone.inc on line 14

I've located the offending file and section of code (below).  How would I fix this code?  What is PHP_TZ supposed to do?  Why doesn't PHP like it?  What can I do instead?

```
//set the timezone
if ($configdata["timezone"] != "") {
    putenv("PHP_TZ=" . stripslashes($configdata["timezone"]));
    putenv("TZ=" . stripslashes($configdata["timezone"]));

    //for >= PHP 5.1
    if(function_exists("date_default_timezone_set")) {
        date_default_timezone_set($configdata["timezone"]);
    }
```

I'm on PHP 5.2.10.  I tried both 'Europe/Zurich', and 'UTC' for the values for $configdata["timezone"] and got the same error for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP_TZ stands for PHP Timezone.

Since the version 5.1 you need to set it through the [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function or from your PHP configuration. From the documentation :

> Note:
>
> Since PHP 5.1.0 (when the date/time functions were rewritten), every call to a date/time  function will generate a E_NOTICE if the timezone isn't valid, **and/or a E_WARNING message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable.**

The easiest fix you could do is the following.

```
//set the timezone
if ($configdata["timezone"] != "") {
    //for >= PHP 5.1
    if(function_exists("date_default_timezone_set")) {
        date_default_timezone_set($configdata["timezone"]);
    // for PHP < 5.1
    } else {
        putenv("PHP_TZ=" . stripslashes($configdata["timezone"]));
        putenv("TZ=" . stripslashes($configdata["timezone"]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default you *SHOULD* be able to set it. See bold section below. It seems your hosting provider disabled it via `safe_mode_protected_env_vars`.

[`bool putenv  ( string $setting  )`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php)

> Adds setting to the server
> environment. The environment variable
> will only exist for the duration of
> the current request. At the end of the
> request the environment is restored to
> its original state.
>
> Setting certain environment variables
> may be a potential security breach.
> The safe_mode_allowed_env_vars
> directive contains a comma-delimited
> list of prefixes. In Safe Mode, the
> user may only alter environment
> variables whose names begin with the
> prefixes supplied by this directive.
> **By default, users will only be able to
> set environment variables that begin
> with PHP_ (e.g. PHP_FOO=BAR).** Note: if
> this directive is empty, PHP will let
> the user modify ANY environment
> variable!
>
> The safe_mode_protected_env_vars
> directive contains a comma-delimited
> list of environment variables, that
> the end user won't be able to change
> using putenv(). These variables will
> be protected even if
> safe_mode_allowed_env_vars is set to
> allow to change them.

HoLyVieR's solution sounds like a good idea.